# Slow Java2D bilinear interpolation in Java 7 on Mac OS X

Tags: performance, macos, java-7, java

I've been testing my app in Java 7 on Mac OS X.  It's running noticeable sluggish.  I used VisualVM to try and track down where the bottleneck was and found linear interpolation to be the culprit:

```
g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
```

To some degree this makes sense of course.  Using interpolation will slow things down.  But I do not see this kind of dramatic difference between using and not using interpolation in Java 6 on OS X.  In Java 6, the difference was almost negligible.  (The images below represent the VisualVM profile of `paintComponent()` after running through a standard animation in my app.)

With interpolation:

[image]

Without interpolation:

[image]

But in Java 7 on OS X, the difference is much more noticeable:

With interpolation:

[image]

Without interpolation:

[image]

I'm guessing the issue lies in hardware acceleration and the transition from Apple to Oracle.  Perhaps Apple's Java 6 was using hardware acceleration to do the interpolation and now Oracle's Java 7 is not.  Does this explain it?  Is there a solution?  I've tried `sun.java2d.opengl=true`.

Update: I found that the issue only appears when using `setRenderingHints()` to apply interpolation.  If you use another method to interpolate the image, such as `AffineTransformOp`, then the performance drop disappears.  For example:

```
g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_SPEED);
AffineTransformOp scaleOp = new AffineTransformOp(scaleTransform, AffineTransformOp.TYPE_BILINEAR);
scaleOp.filter(screenSliceFiltered, screenSliceFilteredScaled);
```

Comment: This suggests this issue will not be fixed for a while: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8017247

Comment: Any idea why the "without interpolation" has dropped so low? Do you think that path has just been optimized in software vis-a-vis 6?

Answer (score 1):

I think you've hit the nail on the head.  In all likelihood the Apple provided JVM leveraged hardware acceleration.  You might ask over on the [Porters group](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/macosx-port/) mailing list of the Mac Port sub-project of OpenJDK.