# Why does this Java app run slow on Mac and not PC?

Tags: java, macos

I have created an application using Java and it runs smoothly on the Windows platform. However, when it is tested on my Macbook Pro Retina 15' with 4960HQ, the displayed frame rates are considerably lower.

I have coded the program to run animations at a constant 60fps and the console shows that 60fps is being drawn on both Mac and Windows. However, the program on Mac looks like it is running at 6-8fps.

Is there special coding methodology tailored for Mac? Or is java simply not optimized for Mac OSX?

**Minimal working sample of code:**

```
    long framerate = 1000 / 60;
    // time the frame began
    long frameStart;
    // number of frames counted this second
    long frameCount = 0;
    // time elapsed during one frame
    long elapsedTime;
    // accumulates elapsed time over multiple frames
    long totalElapsedTime = 0;
    // the actual calculated framerate reported

    while(true){
        frameStart = System.currentTimeMillis();

        world.moveBG(3);

        // calculate the time it took to render the frame
            elapsedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - frameStart;
            // sync the framerate
            try {
                // make sure framerate milliseconds have passed this frame
                if (elapsedTime < framerate) {
                    Thread.sleep(framerate - elapsedTime);
                } else {
                    // don't starve the garbage collector
                    Thread.sleep(5);
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                break;
            }
            ++frameCount;
            totalElapsedTime += (System.currentTimeMillis() - frameStart);
            if (totalElapsedTime > 1000) {
                reportedFramerate = (long) ((double) frameCount
                        / (double) totalElapsedTime * 1000.0);
                // show the framerate in the applet status window
                System.out.println("fps: " + reportedFramerate);
                // repaint();
                frameCount = 0;
                totalElapsedTime = 0;
            }
    }
```

This bit of code handles controlling the fps, it is set to 60fps right now. the `world.moveBG(3)` moves and image across the screen at speed of 3 pixels per frame (which should not be performance intensive as it is a small image). Mac runs this at an apparent 10fps and windows at a smooth 60. The console on both machines display that 60fps is being drawn.

**To clarify, it isn't that the image is moving slower on the screen in Mac than Windows, it is that the movement is extremely choppy on Mac**

Comment: It would be useful to see some code.

Comment: Oh and close vote reasons would be great too...

Comment: Have you tried using an empty loop instead of Thread.sleep?

Comment: @LaszloKorte No i haven't but do you think that Mac doesn't handle `thread.sleep` very well? I will try this and let you know.

Comment: How an empty loop could be better than a Thread.sleep? The compiler could remove the empty loop.

Comment: You should tell us what JVM you use, also what resolution are the screen on osx/windows (because 3px means nothing if you compare a 32inches UHD @3840x2160 screen with a 11 inches @1024x768)

Comment: Probably unrelated to Java.  I'd bet you have more things running on your Mac which are taking up CPU cycles than on the Windows machine.

Comment: @MarcoAcierno Maybe "empty" loop was not quite correct. I meant a loop running until enough time passed. The loop would contain the breaking condition. It could be that the osx scheduler does not handle Thread.sleep that well.

Comment: @MarcoAcierno Yea, the empty loop does not work as fps cannot be controlled very easily. How would i check JVM using netbeans? I am using JDK 1.7 on both Windows and Mac.

Comment: @JeffGohlke It definitely is because of Java; nothing else is running on my Mac. I can easily confirm this by posting CPU readings if you would like.

Comment: @RC I have resolution set to 1680x1050 on Mac and 1080p on the pc. CPU and graphics card components on the pc are not vastly superior to those in the mac.

Comment: I can't tell you why in Mac is worst but I can tell you some parts that you should avoid/change to improve performance. First, don't use System.out.print, this use system interruption, instead use a logger (it's amazing how could your improve with this). And in second part, instead of using while true/sleep it's better if you create a task and use an Executor so you can submit delayed taks (where delay= framerate-elapsedtime).

Comment: @ylun.za why does the empty loop would stop you from controlling the fps? I was suggesting something like: https://gist.github.com/laszlokorte/61a08c8ebe2e1d032663

Comment: @ylun.za Try using Java 6 for comparison.  Java 6 was Apple's implementation and includes lots of hardware acceleration.  Java 7 for OS X is Oracle's implementation and is still inferior in terms of performance.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20108866/slow-java2d-bilinear-interpolation-in-java-7-on-mac-os-x

Comment: @LaszloKorte I'm sorry i misinterpreted what you said. the example you gave makes sense. However, there are several ambiguities. 1. when does `behind` get initialized? 2. `lastTime` is not initialized. @whiskeyspider, thanks i will try that.

Comment: @ylun.za behind get initialized to 0 by default. lastTime should be initialized to the current time at beginning. I fixed that.

Answer (score 1):

The next code starts an executor and schedule the tasks to acomplish your framerate.
Running this on Windows for 3 seconds the last trace I have indicates 179 tasks so almost the 60 tasks per second that you want to acomplish.

Try this code and let me know if improves your performance:

```java
package com.nosolojava.test;

import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class FrameRateExecutor {

private final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getCanonicalName());

final static long framerate = 1000 / 60;

// number of frames counted this second
AtomicInteger frameCount = new AtomicInteger(0);

ScheduledExecutorService executor;
private volatile AtomicBoolean running = new AtomicBoolean(false);

class Task implements Runnable {
    private final long lastTaskTimeStamp;

    public Task() {
        super();
        //get creation time so we can calculate delay after
        this.lastTaskTimeStamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    public void run() {
        // TODO implement logic
        logger.log(
                Level.INFO,
                String.format("Do something, framecount: %02d %d", frameCount.addAndGet(1),
                        System.currentTimeMillis()));

        //calculate when to execute next task and submit
        long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long elapsed = currentTime - lastTaskTimeStamp;
        long delay = (framerate - elapsed) +framerate;

        logger.log(Level.INFO, String.format("elapsed %04d delay %04d", elapsed, delay));

        //check finish condition 
        if (running.get()) {
            executor.schedule(new Task(), delay, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        }
    }
};

public void stop() {
    running.set(false);
    executor.shutdown();

    try {
        executor.awaitTermination(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Error stopping executor", e);
    }

}

public void start() {

    //check if is already up
    if (this.running.compareAndSet(false, true)) {
        //init scheduled executor
        executor = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1);

        //start first task 
        executor.execute(new Task());
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    FrameRateExecutor frameExecutor = new FrameRateExecutor();

    frameExecutor.start();

    Thread.sleep(3000);
    frameExecutor.stop();

}
```

}

Comment: Before i try and implement this into my program, i have one qn. Did you test this on Mac first to see the performance? You only mentioned windows.

Comment: Like I said on my previous comment I can't tell you about Mac but this code is ready to test with no customization, just try on Mac and see the logs and let me know please it's been an effort to write it.

Comment: It is actually quite difficult to try and include this into what i have. Working on it

Comment: Just change where it says // TODO implement logic to world.moveBG(3);

Comment: I tested on a Mac virtual machine and for 3 seconds it executes 174 tasks, in a real machine should be better.

Comment: Yes it does seem to run faster however, this solution is not suitable for the entire program. Thanks for the suggestions though.

Comment: Just take this example like a different pattern. I hope this would help you in future implementations. Thanks.