# Simple 2D java game lags on mac

Tags: java, macos, 2d, lag

I have created a simple top-down 2D java game over the past week and a half. It runs perfectly on my windows computer, and a few of my friends have run it fine on their computers as well.

Recently, I have tried loading the game up on my mac, but it seems to lag horribly and slows down my whole computer. This only happens when the game is running and returns to normal when I exit it.

I have attached one of my classes below that could cause the problem, although I believe it most likely has something to do with my computer.

```
public class Game implements Runnable {
//DISPLAY
private Display display;
private int width, height;
public String title;
//THREADS
private boolean running = false;
private Thread thread;
//BUFFERING AND HRAPHICS
private BufferStrategy bs;
private Graphics g;

// Statess
public States gameState, island;
private States menuState;

// Input
private KeyManager keyManager;
private MouseManager mouseManager;
//UI

// Handler
private Handler handler;
//TIMER
Timer myTimer = new Timer();
public static int seconds = 0;
int count = 0;
//PAUSE
private boolean paused = false;
public Game(String title, int width, int height) {
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.title = title;
    keyManager = new KeyManager();
    mouseManager = new MouseManager();


}

private void init() {
    display = new Display(title, width, height);
    display.getFrame().addKeyListener(keyManager);
    display.getFrame().addMouseListener(mouseManager);
    display.getFrame().addMouseMotionListener(mouseManager);
    display.getCanvas().addMouseListener(mouseManager);
    display.getCanvas().addMouseMotionListener(mouseManager);
    Assets.init();

    handler = new Handler(this);

    gameState = new GameState(handler, 9, 79, 1502, 79);
    island = new Island(handler, 20, 190, 1450, 190);
    menuState = new MenuState(handler);
    States.setState(menuState);

}



private void tick() {
    keyManager.tick();
    setPaused();
    if(!paused){
        States.getState().tick();
        if(count == 0){
        if(States.getState() != menuState){
            myTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    seconds++;
                }
            }, 1000, 1000);
        count = 1;  
        }
        }
        //System.out.println(seconds);
    }
    render();
}


public void paused(Graphics g){
    g.drawString("Paused", 750, 200);
}

private void render() {

    bs = display.getCanvas().getBufferStrategy();
    if (bs == null) {
        display.getCanvas().createBufferStrategy(3);
        return;
    }
    g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
    // Clear Screen
    g.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
    // Draw Here!
    //Rendering
    //State render

        States.getState().render(g);
        //UI
        if(States.getState() != menuState){
            if(paused)
            paused(g);
        }
    // End Drawing!
    bs.show();
    g.dispose();
}



public void run() {

    init();

    int fps = 60;
    double timePerTick = 1000000000 / fps;
    double delta = 0;
    long now;
    long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
    long timer = 0;
    //int ticks = 0;

    while (running) {
        now = System.nanoTime();
        delta += (now - lastTime) / timePerTick;
        timer += now - lastTime;
        lastTime = now;

        if (delta >= 1) {
            tick();

            //ticks++;
            delta--;
        }

        if (timer >= 1000000000) {

            //ticks = 0;
            timer = 0;
        }
    }

    stop();

}

public States getGameState(){
    return gameState;
}
public KeyManager getKeyManager() {
    return keyManager;
}

public MouseManager getMouseManager() {
    return mouseManager;
}

public int getWidth() {
    return width;
}

public int getHeight() {
    return height;
}
//TIMER


public synchronized void start() {
    if (running)
        return;
    running = true;
    thread = new Thread(this);
    thread.start();
}

public synchronized void stop() {
    if (!running)
        return;
    running = false;
    try {
        thread.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public boolean isPaused() {
    return paused;
}

public void setPaused() {
    if(handler.getKeyManager().keyJustPressed(KeyEvent.VK_U))
         paused = !paused;
}
}
```

Display.java

```
public class Display {

    private String title;
    private int height;
    private int width;
    private Canvas canvas;
    private JFrame frame;

    public Display(String title, int width, int height) {
        this.title = title;
        this.height = height;
        this.width = width;
        createDisplay();
    }

    public void createDisplay() {
        // Make frame
        frame = new JFrame(title);
        frame.setSize(width, height);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        // canvas to draw graphics
        canvas = new Canvas();
        canvas.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        canvas.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        canvas.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        canvas.setFocusable(false);
        // Display canvas through jframe
        frame.add(canvas);
        frame.pack();
    }
    public Canvas getCanvas(){
        return canvas;
    }
    public JFrame getFrame(){
        return frame;
    }
}
```

Comment: Improve readability

Answer (score 0):

It's a problem related with your OS, improve your code following these questions already asked:

[Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22869740/why-does-this-java-app-run-slow-on-mac-and-not-pc)

[Link 2](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/17141/mac-os-some-apps-mostly-java-are-very-slow-at-first-loading)

Also try to update your Java version and if possible make your code shorter.