# Java game using lots of CPU on MacBooks but not Linux or Windows

Tags: java, macos, awt

I'm making a Java game for all platforms using the Java awt libraries but I've run into an issue - the game has very poor FPS on all Macbook Pros it's been run on, but runs fine on Linux and Windows machines. Using the activity monitor I can see that the game is using almost 100% of the CPU while running on the Macs, but barely any on the Windows machine. Has anyone come across this issue and solved it?

Here's the main game loop, commenting out `Thread.sleep(waitTime);` doesn't improve it, which was my first thought:

```
    while(running){

        startTime = System.nanoTime();

        update();
        render();
        draw();

        urdTime = (System.nanoTime() - startTime) /1000000;
        waitTime = targetTime - urdTime;

        try{
            Thread.sleep(waitTime);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

EDIT: breaking everything down to work out where the bottleneck was, the function that is taking up too much time (around 0.07 seconds each call) is the line `g2.drawImage(image,0,0,null);` where g2 is of type Graphics and created with this line `Graphics g2 = getGraphics();` and image is a BufferedImage created once using `new BufferedImage(1600, 900, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB)`.

Also interesting to note it that when the size (1600x900) is reduced the game runs much faster.

Comment: My assumption is there is some operations in your code that takes (a lot) longer on mac than on other os', try checking how long the thread is actually sleeping, im assuming this will be a lot lower (if not 0 or lower), and so just never sleeping, hogging all cpu... Try testing the time it takes to execute update(), render() and draw()... see which method takes much longer to execute than would be normal, and just narrowing down the problem to the actual (slow) code.

Comment: Yes, I have.  If possible you may want to target Java 6 in OS X instead of 7 or 8.  The Java 6 JRE was created by Apple and uses more hardware acceleration than Oracle's 7 or 8.  See this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20108866/slow-java2d-bilinear-interpolation-in-java-7-on-mac-os-x

Comment: @Subler narrowed it down, but there's not a lot I can do about the method that's causing the issue. Found others with the same problem but the fix that worked for them didn't help mine.

Comment: @whiskeyspider looking at Eclipse>About Eclipse>Installation Details and looking for the line 'java.runtime.version=' it says "java.runtime.version=1.6.0_65-b14-466.1-11M4716" which I believe means it's running under Java 6, but I'm probably wrong - not great with the whole configuration thing